# R - error "variable lengths differ"

Tags: r

```
> #transforming length of time
> transLOT<-log(LengthofTimemin)
> 
> #checking for outliers
> fit<-lm(transLOT~DielEnd+TideEnd+TideStart+Moonphase+TideStart*Moonphase, data=resdata)
> outlierTest(fit)
    rstudent unadjusted p-value Bonferonni p
295 4.445284         1.1025e-05    0.0052808
> 
> #getting rid of the outlier data in row 295
> rdata<-resdata[-295, ]
> print(rdata[294:296,5:10])
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  DepartureDate       DepartureTime        LengthofTime LengthofTimemin EventLengthCategories
         <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>           <dbl>                 <chr>
1    2016-09-19 1899-12-30 23:46:46 1899-12-30 00:05:49        5.816667                  5-15
2    2016-09-20 1899-12-30 01:55:28 1899-12-30 00:01:20        1.333333                    <5
3    2016-09-20 1899-12-30 04:07:28 1899-12-30 00:01:21        1.350000                    <5
> newfit<-lm(transLOT~DielEnd+TideEnd+TideStart+Moonphase+TideStart*Moonphase, na.action=na.exclude, data=rdata)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = transLOT ~ DielEnd + TideEnd +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'DielEnd')
> #now all of a sudden the variable lengths differ
```

I understand that the problem occurs with the removal of the row of data but I assumed that na.exclude would account for it. After thoroughly searching, I am unable to determine why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because in your first step you created a separate variable outside of your data frame, `transLOT<-log(LengthofTimemin)`. When you remove a row from the data, `transLOT` is unchanged. Even worse than differing lengths, your data doesn't line up any more - if the different lengths were ignored, your rows of data would be "off by one" compared to the response after the row you removed.

The simple solution is to create your `transLOT` variable in the data frame. Then, whenever you do things to the data (like remove rows), the same thing is done to `transLOT`.

```
resdata$transLOT <- log(resdata$LengthofTimemin)
```

Note that I also use the `resdata$LengthofTimemin` rather than `LengthofTimemin` which you seem to have in your workspace. Did you use `attach()` at some point? You shouldn't use `attach` for exactly this reason. Keep variables in the data frame!

Comment: Thank you very much! I did indeed use attach() earlier in the code. I had previously not been instructed against it, but from now on I will use $ to link my data frame.

Comment: ther good options exist - you seem to be using `dplyr` already (at least your `rdata` is a tibble), so `mutate` is a nice alternative that both keeps data in your data frame and saves you from having to re-type the name of the data frame hundreds of times.